# How do you export TS for use without bundlers?

Tags: typescript, package.json, tsconfig

I have a tiny package with `package.json` like this:

```json
{
  "name": "@nomatter/utils",
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "Dave Stein",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "tsc:watch": "tsc --watch --preserveWatchOutput"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "main": "out-tsc/src/index.js",
  "types": "out-tsc/src/index.d.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "description": ""
}
```

The TS Config in my exported package and the app importing it is the following (Except `declaration` is only in the exported package):

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2018",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "rootDir": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "declaration": true
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"],
}
```

I can't seem to figure the right configuration for `main` and `types` in `package.json`.

In my app that does `import @nomatter/utils`, the TSC compiler will complain it can't resolve my import.

I would think TSC can handle reading the imported `js` files that were generated from TSC. When I look at `out-tsc/src/index.js` it has one basic `export` that I expect to be there based on all the config. Not sure why it can't be found?

[image: picture showing folder structure of out-tsc]

`index.ts` is just `export const signupSchema = {};` while `index.d.ts` is just `export declare const signupSchema: {};`

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to add `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`. It is required when using `.js` extensions with ESM. See [Determining module system](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#determining-module-system) in the Node.js documentation.

Comment: Are you saying the app doing the import needs that? Because my sample above shows I am doing `"type": "module"` in the `util` package I am importing.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75368633/how-do-you-export-ts-for-use-without-bundlers?noredirect=1#comment133002088_75368633) @DaveStein Yes, that is correct. Also, will you please update the question with a [mre]? It should include the full `package.json`, `tsconfig.json`, source code etc for all projects/files involved.

Comment: Also, did you install the dependency package using [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-link) or using another method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct, as it was shown in my original question.

```
  "type": "module",
  "main": "out-tsc/src/index.js",
  "types": "out-tsc/src/index.d.ts",
```

As @jsejckson hinted, my symlinking was bad. Using `npm link` properly resolved the issue.